# Long respond time because of Mod_SPDY or Session , Apache2 server

Tags: php, session, nginx, apache2, spdy

I'm work on an apache2 server (nginx)  and for some reason the respond times have been very long. It can take up to 30Sec to get a respond from the server.

I have check the PHP code and also added a timer to it so it can’t be the code. I have also created a very simple dummy file but the delay is still there.
I have also restarted all services but the problem is still there.

I keep seeing the following Errors in the error-log and suspecting that it might be related to a session problem:

[Sun Oct 06 16:50:03 2013] [error] [client 69.201.188.61] [mod_spdy/0.9.4.1-397] [32734:32734:ERROR:spdy_session.cc(304)] Session error: INVALID_CONTROL_FRAME

[Sun Oct 06 15:32:13 2013] [error] [client 84.168.213.116] [mod_spdy/0.9.4.1-397] [18811:18811:ERROR:apache_spdy_session_io.cc(88)] ap_get_brigade failed with status 104: Connection reset by peer

I Googled these error logs but couldn’t really find anything.
Any suggestions?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have HTTPS enabled? I'm having the same issue and i'm suspecting.